# What is the best server client communication protocol to use in Android and iOS?

Tags: java, android, ios, protocols

We have a server application (implemented in Java) that will provide some data for our mobile apps. The apps will be created for Android and iOS.

Which is the best protocol / library for this purpose? The overhead of the protocol should be as small as possible.

Thanks.

Edit: It should be a request->response szenario. Data lost is not acceptable. The answer could contain a long list of data and therfore less overhead is required.

The client shall request the data (a specified key and some definied parameters) e.g. "give me all file from folder x that have the extension y". The server answers with the list.

The first idea was using XMLRPC, but the generated responses are too large.

Comment: Best for what? Do you require each and every bit of data to be delivered, or are lost data OK (e.g. VoIP)? Do you need integrity and confidentiality assurances? Do you need it to have small latency? Too many variables IMO.

Comment: also, what are you transferring? do you have 5 message types? 10? 50? are the messages simple or complex?

Comment: @Omry & @piskvor for real efficiency or if your streaming stuff you're 100% right but i find choosing anything other than HTTP, at least initially, is premature optimization. especially if it looks even vaguely like it is a request/response pattern

Comment: @tobyodavies : http is just a meta protocol. it's not much more useful than saying tcp. what protocol you chose (hand coded binary, text based, object serialization, protobuf/thrift serialization) depends on many factors.

Comment: I've not seen that many _formal_ _reusable_ protocols built on top of HTTP and he's asking for libraries, most people build their own protocol on top of the HTTP... i usually send JSON or XML over HTTP. Though it definately is heading that way (which is a Good Thing TM)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For most applications, HTTP(S) is the best protocol to use. The overhead (i.e. headers) is pretty small, the transfer can be gzipped, the connection can be secured (via SSL). Also, ports 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS) will be open in 99% of cases. Other ports are not -- for example some carriers block all other ports unless you pay extra.

---

As for the implementation, I suggest a [RESTful web service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#RESTful_web_services) using the [JSON](http://json.org/) format. JSON is well standardized, has small overhead and you have good libraries for working with it in any language (check out [`org.json`](http://d.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html), which is bundled with Android but can be [downloaded](http://json.org/java/) as standalone for other applications as well). Check out this question, too:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library

Comment: I think HTTP is the protocol of choice. What still needed are recommendations for ready-to-go libraries that are recommendable and still meet the requirements.

Comment: "As for a format, I suggest JSON over a REST-like API." 
Is it just me or is this sentence indeed nonsense?

Comment: @Serguei REST refers to the way resources are located and accessed (i.e. using HTTP GET/POST/PUT/DELETE and giving each resource a URL (Unique Resource Locator)). JSON refers to the actual format used to describe resources. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#RESTful_web_services). So no, it is not nonsense.

Comment: Oh now I see what you were getting at; I'm familiar with both JSON and REST but from the way that sentence is written I initially thought you were advocating JSON vs REST as if they were both data formats. ("..over a REST-like protocol." would have been clear, for me at least)

Comment: @Serguei thanks for the notice, I edited my answer. Hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: For the library to use in communications, use AFNetworking - it has a subclass that understands and automatically parses JSON.  I would not worry about which JSON parser you are using unless you have really large JSON (say over 10k or so).

Answer (score 3):

Use Jackson parser or Gson parser instead of JSON Parser.

1.[Jackson](http://capdroid.wordpress.com/2012/07/13/android-simple-json-parsing-using-jackson-apis/) is 2X faster than JSON and it is suitable for parsing complex and extremely big jsons.

2.[Gson](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html) competitively faster than JSON.

Answer (score 0):

In My Opinion, you should use REST/SOAP web sevices based on document-oriented structures, This will be helpful in the Large response.

You can also integerate [Apache SOLR](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) for this Purpose this is used for Indexing the Large Datasets and is even much faster and it is also REST enabled, you can index your data in the SOLR cores and then create REST calls from Client i.e. IOS, Android, PHP etc. so the documents will already be processed and you just need to add filters and other things as required on client.

Let me know if you want any more help regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Another protocol you can use today (2021) is **gRPC**. It has many advantages over classic REST APIs for mobile apps, namely faster serialization and smaller data load (because it's binary, not JSON).

Because of that it's also [easier for device bateries](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/grpc).

> Transmitting data from mobile devices to a backend server can be a very resource-intensive process. Using the standard HTTP/1.1 protocol,
> frequent connections from a mobile device to a cloud service can drain
> the battery, increase latency, and block other apps from connecting.
> By default, gRPC runs on top of HTTP/2, which introduces
> bi-directional streaming, flow control, header compression, and the
> ability to multiplex requests over a single TCP/IP connection. The
> result is that gRPC can reduce resource usage, resulting in lower
> response times between your app and services running in the cloud,
> reduced network usage, and longer battery life for client running on
> mobile devices.